# Не могу получить правильную длинну массива, выдаёт ноль

Tags: java, массивы, split

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays {

static String newConditionalYesterday;
static String newConditionalTooday;
static String[] brokenNewConditionalDays = new String[3];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays();
}

//Ввод условных дат
static void SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays() throws Exception {

    System.out.print("\n Введите новую условную вчерашнюю дату по типу:\"17.11.2018\":");
    Scanner newConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDaysObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    newConditionalYesterday = newConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDaysObject.next();

    System.out.print(" Введите новую условную вчерашнюю дату по типу:\"18.11.2018\":");
    newConditionalTooday = newConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDaysObject.next();

    checkTypeOfEnteredData();
    System.out.print(" Новая условная вчерашняя дата:".concat(newConditionalYesterday).concat("\n Новая условная сегодняшняя дата:").concat(newConditionalTooday));

}

//Проверка условной даты на соответствие выбранному типу
static void checkTypeOfEnteredData() throws Exception {

    //Проверка наличия трёх сигментов даты, разделённых точками
    try {

        brokenNewConditionalDays = newConditionalYesterday.split(".");
        if(brokenNewConditionalDays.length != 3){
            SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays();
        }

        brokenNewConditionalDays = newConditionalTooday.split(".");
        if(brokenNewConditionalDays.length != 3){
            SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays();
        }

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        SetConditionalYesterdaysAndToodaysDays();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx `"."` (точка) - это любой символ. Его нужно экранировать (`"\\."`)